# How to connect a client to a server on different networks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I connect a client which is on a different network to my server? What IP should I put on each side? IPv4 or my Public Ip? Should I open ports? UDP, TCP or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client needs to know the IP address of your server and the port the server is listening on.   See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

Based on your comments you are setting up your server on your home network. If so you can determine the IP address your clients need to connect to by typing "what is my ip" in your browser's search. Next you will need to set up port forwarding on your home network's router.  You will also need to know the IP address of the computer you will be running your server code on.

Comment: My public ip address?

Comment: Depends. Is the server in your house behind a router and the client outside your home network?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed.